# Why doesn't my process start at boot? (OpenWrt)

Tags: c, linux, openwrt, init.d

I defined the following script (it's called pcap):

```
#!/bin/sh /etc/rc.common
# Example script
# Copyright (C) 2007 OpenWrt.org
 
START=10
STOP=15
 
start() {        
        echo start
        ./delete_pcap
        # commands to launch application
}                 
 
stop() {          
        echo stop
        # commands to kill application 
}
```

I put this script in the /etc/init.d folder. When I do `/etc/init.d/pcap start`, the start function is executed and the delete_pcap (in C language, which is in the same `/etc/init.d` folder) program is executed correctly. Anyway, if I do `/etc/init.d/pcap enable`, that should execute the delete_pcap program at each reboot, the program doesn't start when the system start. I checked in the folder `/etc/rc.d` and I have `S10pcap` file (created when I do enable). So, where is the problem?

Why isn't `delete_pcap` executed at the system start?

Comment: Why would init's current directory be /etc/unit.d?

Comment: I read the documentation (https://oldwiki.archive.openwrt.org/doc/techref/initscripts). If there is an error, can you tell me where is it? I'm inexperienced about OpenWrt.

Comment: Is it the wrong directory?

Comment: Put the full path to delete_pcap in the script.

Comment: Note that on Unix, BSD--and Linux, too--they are "directories" and not the Windows concept of "folders" which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try using new service management tools like procd:

https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-developer/procd-init-scripts

example for your app

```
#!/bin/sh /etc/rc.common

APP=/usr/bin/pcap # specify the full path this is example

USE_PROCD=1
START=98 # indicates that process should start last
STOP=99

start_service() { # Override this to start your app
    procd_open_instance
    procd_set_param command "$APP"
    procd_close_instance
}
```

No need to override other functions like stop start restart

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.